# Breaking ElGammal by solving discrete logarithm in subgroups with Sage

Tags: group-theory, cryptography, sagemath, discrete-logarithms

I'm working in the context of ElGamal encryption problem as describe in the second image of [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/why-is-it-claimed-that-elgamal-is-worse-than-rsa) post. In my problem, I work on $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ with p prime. I'm told that I should look for subgroups of index two so that the discrete logarithm problem becomes easier. I'm working with sage.

1. How can I look for the subgroup of index 2 in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ with sage?
2. Once I find the subgroup of index 2 how would I solve the discrete logarithm problem on it? How would I use this result for solve the discrete logarithm problem in the whole group?

Comment: Before working too much on this you may want to get acquainted with some basic group theory, as that is more or less a minimum requirement for this. For example, the group has a unique subgroup of index $2$, so there is no "suitable" needed.

Comment: Yes, precisely (once you add "unique" to that).

Comment: You are using SAGE. The command **primitive_root(4441)** will give the primitive root for the prime 4441 (Yes, I checked this number is prime). Its square mod that prime will be a generator for the unique subgroup of index 2. So much for SAGE and group theory. Now read the details of  ElGamal encryption scheme and break it using this   info.

Comment: @PVanchinathan how would I write the group generated by element in sage?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341390/sage-implementation-of-discrete-logarithm-in-subgroup-of-group-of-units where this is answered.